# Reference for Poisson geometry

Tags: reference-request, poisson-geometry

Is there any good reference for Poisson geometry/Poisson manifolds out there? I would like to give a deep look to the subject, but all I seem to be able to find are short chapters or interludes in text about symplectic geometry.

Looking a bit around on the web, the only thing I found is [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=z1r2BwAAQBAJ&pg=PR5&lpg=PR5&dq=introduction%20to%20poisson%20manifolds&source=bl&ots=NT16L6E8_J&sig=KWk1weRa8pNeU9fiE8MgkHgVd_0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBDgKahUKEwiWzMefno7IAhVJPBoKHRDaBXk#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20poisson%20manifolds&f=false). Has anybody read it? And if so, is it good or is there something better?

---

For those left wondering: the book in the link above seems a good introduction. A more advanced text is given by the book *Poisson Geometry, Deformation Quantisation and Group Representations* (Cambridge University Press).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiki give some references depending on which kind of book you are looking for

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold

or to have a look on scanned book :

http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=poisson+geometry&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def